# PHP date format, remove time and more

Tags: php, date, datetime, date-format

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert one date format into another in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2167916/convert-one-date-format-into-another-in-php)

Starting from:

```
$date = '2012-09-09 03:09:00'
```

I would like to do two things.

1. Remove the time from the string, so it will become `"2012-09-09"`.
2. Calculate how many years, days, and hours have passed since this date
   using the server current date/time/timezone.

Could anyone help me figure this out?

Comment: Your second question is a duplicate of [How to calculate the difference between two dates using PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/676824/how-to-calculate-the-difference-between-two-dates-using-php)

Answer (score 53, accepted):

Use [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php):

```
$date = '2012-09-09 03:09:00';

$createDate = new DateTime($date);

$strip = $createDate->format('Y-m-d');
var_dump($strip); // string(10) "2012-09-09"

$now = new DateTime();
$difference = $now->diff($createDate, true);
var_dump($difference);

/* object(DateInterval)#3 (8) {
  ["y"]=>
  int(0)
  ["m"]=>
  int(0)
  ["d"]=>
  int(7)
  ["h"]=>
  int(13)
  ["i"]=>
  int(4)
  ["s"]=>
  int(38)
  ["invert"]=>
  int(0)
  ["days"]=>
  int(7)
} */
```

Answer (score 26):

```
$date = '2012-09-09 03:09:00';
$dt = new DateTime($date);

echo $dt->format('Y-m-d');

$interval = $dt->diff(new DateTime());
```

You can use the interval as it suits you. See http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php